# Received git error: 'fatal: Unable to read current working directory: Permission denied'

Tags: git, github

I'm new to Git. I tried to read my Git status and received this error. What does this mean and how can I fix this? Important to note that I want to commit from my work laptop to a personal account. This used to work before and now suddenly not anymore.

I tried 'git status' and received the error message in the title. I want to commit my new code to my repository, but it seems that I cannot access my repository.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems local and not related to the reason you are trying to push to your private account.

Try the following:

1. Check directory permissions where your local repository is located
2. Check you access rights to the directory and content (If it's shared
   machine or network, this could cause issues)